# Why is Google Chrome locking my SD card from being ejected?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, gmail, sd-card, lock

A couple times now I've been unable to eject an SD card I've inserted while Chrome was running.  Lockhunter says that Chrome has something open.  Both times Gmail has been one of the tabs.  This time the only other tab was a blog.  What business does Chrome have locking files on my SD card when I didn't e.g. tell Chrome to open a file there or anything like that?  How can I stop it from doing this?

This is on XPSP3 on a netbook.

Comment: What files were locked?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure.  Next time I'll see if I can see.  I think the first time I looked, it didn't actually say, or it said the whole drive (as if it were browsing E: or something.)